# Having trouble implementing two-way-gridview

Tags: android

I think it's my adapter where the problem lies, it worked on a normal GridView, I assumed I would just be able to switch the two-way-gridview in place of the GridView. But now one place where it is used nothing is shown and the other place the images don't fill the view vertically and there are more columns than I have set.

Here's the adapter code:

```
public final class CoverGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList;

public CoverGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the image URL for the current position.
    //String url = getItem(position);
    final HashMap<String,String> game = getItem(position);

    CoverImageView view = (CoverImageView) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = new CoverImageView(context);
        view.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, GameActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", game); //Optional parameters
                context.startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
    }



    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso.with(context) //
            .load(game.get(GameDiscoveryFragment.TAG_SUPER_IMAGE)) //
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher) //TODO: placeholder image
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher) //TODO: error image
            .fit() //
            .into(view);

    return view;
}

@Override public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override public HashMap<String,String> getItem(int position) {
    //return urls.get(position);
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

And a link to the GitHub project https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Edit: A little bit more information. I played round a little bit more and while no images are shown in portrait, they do appear when I rotate the device. So maybe the xml will also help.

```
<com.ryanjohnstone.gamediscovery.app.com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#E8E8E8"
        android:id="@+id/similar_games_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
        app:rowHeight="80dp"
        app:numColumns="@integer/similar_column_count"
        app:numRows="1"
        app:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        app:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
        app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
        app:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

Edit 2: The reason nothing is showing in portrait is I need to set the columnWidth attribute. I don't see why this is necessary when I have the number of columns set. It isn't necessary on GridView. Is there a way in xml to set the value to the screen width divided by the number of columns?

Edit 3: Setting app:stretchMode to columnWidth has fixed the issue in portrait mode, I now see the images and they fill their row and column. I'm still having a problem in landscape of them not filling. Here's the current xml:

```
<com.ryanjohnstone.gamediscovery.app.com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#E8E8E8"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
        app:numColumns= "@integer/column_count"
        app:numRows="auto_fit"
        app:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        app:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        app:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
        app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
        app:gravity="center"/>
```

Edit 4: To clarify, it's working as expected in portrait with vertical scrolling. Portrait with horizontal scrolling isn't working how I'd like. It shows all images instead of the number I put in numColumns.

Edit 5: I copied and pasted my xml into the sample application of the git hub project and it works as expected, so I'm back to believing my problem lies within my adapter.

Comment: Maybe you link to the two way gridview source you use (I guess the github project?)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Edited the question with a link to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E8E8E8"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"

app:numColumns="auto_fit"
app:numRows="1"

app:stretchMode="columnWidth"
app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
app:gravity="center"
```